# Unable to stop nagios nrpe server

Tags: ubuntu, nagios, nrpe

> Note: I am referring to an old Ubuntu 14.04 ! :( Don't blame me, it's not my fault.

I have this process

[image]

When I kill, something restart it automatically.

I need to stop it!

I tried what follows without succcess

```
# systemctl disable nrpe.service
# systemctl stop nrpe.service
# systemctl status nrpe.service
nrpe.service - Nagios Remote Plugin Executor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nrpe.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-17 09:44:23 CEST; 14min ago
     Docs: http://www.nagios.org/documentation
 Main PID: 21974 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: name=dsystemd:/system/nrpe.service

Aug 17 09:44:23 localhost nrpe[21974]: Starting up daemon
Aug 17 09:44:23 localhost nrpe[21974]: Bind to port 5666 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
```

I tried also

```
# /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server stop
# /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server status
#
```

But in htop the process is still running

I queried status of service using old way

```
# service --status-all
[ - ]  nagios-nrpe-server

# service nagios-nrpe-server stop
```

But the process is still here (with a different PID, so it's auto restarted)

Also

```
# systemctl stop nagios-nrpe-server
Failed to issue method call: Unit nagios-nrpe-server.service not loaded.
# systemctl disable nagios-nrpe-server
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved !

```
# stop nrpe
# rm -f /etc/init/nrpe.conf
```

Found instructions here: https://support.nagios.com/kb/print-741.html